# Returning a String as JSON response when run as a jar file fails with 500 status code

Tags: java, rest, jar, jersey, shadow

The fat jar which i have created returns the json from a file correctly when running within the IDE(IntelliJ). But, i have problems executing it as a jar. This is a Dropwizard application with Guice. I have the following in my build.gradle

```
jar {
        manifest {
            attributes "Implementation-Title": "Symphony Service"
            attributes "Implementation-Version": '1.0'
            attributes "Main-Class" : 'com.symphony.api.SymphonyService'
        }

        doFirst {
            from (configurations.runtime.resolve().collect {
                    it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
            }) {
                exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
                exclude 'META-INF/*.SF'
                exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'
                exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA'
            }
        }
    }
```

And this in my controller.

```
@GET
@Path("/segments/{segmentid}/result")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String result(@PathParam("segmentid") String segmentId) throws IOException {
    String response = null;
    URL url = Resources.getResource("response.json");
    try {
            response = Resources.toString(url, Charsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}
```

Everything works fine from within the IDE. But when i package it as a jar and then run it i get the following error:

ERROR [2014-03-12 05:13:44,304] com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse: A message body writer for Java class `java.lang.String`, and Java type class `java.lang.String`, and MIME media type application/json was not found

ERROR [2014-03-12 05:13:44,305] com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse: The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
*/* ->

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider
```

Following is my SPI file for the MessageBodyWriter -
META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter:

```
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.RenderedImageProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.MimeMultipartProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormMultivaluedMapProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$App
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$Text
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$App
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$Text
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$App
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$Text
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter
com.sun.jersey.atom.rome.impl.provider.entity.AtomFeedProvider
com.sun.jersey.atom.rome.impl.provider.entity.AtomEntryProvider
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$App
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$App
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$App
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$App
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$App
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONWithPaddingProvider
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy
com.sun.jersey.fastinfoset.impl.provider.entity.FastInfosetRootElementProvider
com.sun.jersey.fastinfoset.impl.provider.entity.FastInfosetJAXBElementProvider
com.sun.jersey.fastinfoset.impl.provider.entity.FastInfosetListElementProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.RenderedImageProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.MimeMultipartProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormMultivaluedMapProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$App
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$Text
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$App
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$Text
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$App
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$Text
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter
com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider
```

I feel this is happening because the entry

```
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
```

is repeated in the META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter file. 
When I manually create the jar after removing duplicates from that file, it works.
I have still not found a way to get the file to merge correctly. Tried the shadow plugin for gradle but have trouble getting it to work.

-Amith

FIXED: Got the gradle shadow plugin working and it works now without any tweaks

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:0.8'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'shadow'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Implementation-Title": "Symphony Service"
        attributes "Implementation-Version": '1.0'
        attributes "Main-Class" : 'com.experian.symphony.api.SymphonyService'
    }

     /*excludes {
            exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
            exclude 'META-INF/*.SF'
            exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'
            exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA'
        } */
}

shadow {
    destinationDir = 'build/distributions'
    classifier = '1.0'

    exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
    exclude 'META-INF/*.SF'
    exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'
    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA'
}
```

Comment: The 500 error means something went wrong on your server (i.e. some exception was thrown). Check your logs for the stack trace of that exception and include it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you set this in your web.xml you won't have the error. This was what I did to overcome the problem if mapping basic types.

I think the basic issue is that the default MessageWriter uses the jaxb annotations (@XmlRootElement) to process the object and since base types like String, Number, Double, Integer etc do not have these, you have to use the default pojo mapper which will process use jackson's ObjectMapper class. The other options you can use are to wrap the String in another object to be returned or implement an @Provider that implements `MessageBodyWriter<String>` that will convert the string to json. Hope this helps.

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/json.html

**Web.xml Configuration**

```
       <init-param>
           <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
           <param-value>true</param-value>
       </init-param>
```

**Guice Configuration**

```
@Override
protected void configureServlets() {
    serve("/rest/v1/*").with(GuiceContainer.class, createJerseyParams());
}


private Map<String, String> createJerseyParams() {
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

    params.put("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true");
    return params;
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question to add more details on my findings.